# What is the bonus XP pool and how does it affect the gain of XP?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 there you can often find a "Pool of Reflection" which adds to a so-called bonus experience pool. This bonus pool gets invalidated if the avatar dies.

How does this bonus pool affect the gain of experience?

Even if the marker for the bonus pool is at the rightmost point you still seem to have to collect XP points from monster kills. So how does this bonus XP pool work?

Even if though the question may seem trivial, I haven't found any explanation, yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pool of Reflection creates a bonus pool of XP and then grants a 25% bonus to earned XP (stacking on top of other effects) until the pool is exhausted.

Anything you do that generates XP (monster kills, finish quests) will grant bonus XP.

http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Pool_of_Reflection

Answer (score 1):

You receive 25% more experience from all sources until your experience amount reaches the bonus "dot" on the bar.
If the bonus is at the rightmost position, it will carry over to next level.